# Enviar valor da view para controller C# ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso passar um ID de um forach dentro de um form da minha view para o controller, mas não encontrei a melhor forma de fazer isso.

Tentei chamar um HiddenFor com o ID no foreach ou chamar o valor por FormCollection, mas não obtive resultados concretos em nenhum dos dois casos. Alguém teria a melhor solução?

**view:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AdicionaGestor", "Ti01", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <!-- Modal Gestor -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalGestor" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <!--Passa parametro CadastroID para o controller-->
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CadastroID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-left">Adicionar um gestor a solicitação</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UsuarioGestor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                    <p>Selecione o recurso que você deseja atrelar a este gestor:</p>
                    <br />

                    @foreach (var item in (List<Ti01Model>)TempData["TarefasInfra"])
                    {
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.RecursoGestor, item.Recursos)
                        <label for="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Recursos)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Recursos)</label>

                        <!--Passa parametro IdRecurso para o controller-->
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.IdRecurso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                        <br />
                    }

                    @foreach (var item in (List<Ti01Model>)TempData["TarefasSistemas"])
                    {
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.RecursoGestor, item.Recursos)
                        <label for="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Recursos)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Recursos)</label>

                        <!--Passa parametro IdRecurso para o controller-->
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.IdRecurso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                        <br />
                    }

                    <br />
                    <br />
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ObsAddGestor, new { @class = "form-control", rows = "4", cols = "4" })

                </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Adicionar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**controller:**

```
public ActionResult AdicionaGestor(Ti01Model model)
        {
            HttpCookie CookieNomeCompleto = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("NomeCompleto");
            HttpCookie CookieUsuario = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("usuario");
            HttpCookie CookieGestor = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("gestor");
            String usuario = CookieUsuario.Value;
            String nome = CookieNomeCompleto.Value;

            Ti01Dal dal = new Ti01Dal();
            AuthoAD ad = new AuthoAD();
            Ti01 t = new Ti01();

            t.CadastroID = model.CadastroID;
            t.IdRecurso = t.IdRecurso;
            t.UsuarioGestor = model.UsuarioGestor;
            t.NomeGestor = ad.RetornaUserInfoAD(t.UsuarioGestor).Nome;
            t.EmailGestor = ad.RetornaUserInfoAD(t.UsuarioGestor).Email;
            t.RecursoGestor = model.RecursoGestor;

            t.UsuarioMov = usuario;
            t.Observacao = "Adicionou " + t.NomeGestor + "(" + t.UsuarioGestor + ")" + " como gestor/aprovador para a tarefa:" + t.RecursoGestor;

            try
            {

                //ADICIONA O GESTOR NA TABELA TI01E
                dal.AdicionaGestor(t);

                ////ENVIO DE EMAIL - NOTIFICAÇÃO
                //if (dal.VerificaAprovacoes(t.CadastroID) == 2)
                //{
                //    EmailSolicitacaoAprovada(t);
                //}


                GetUser();
                GetUnidades();
                GetCargos();
                GetCentrosCusto();
                ModelState.Clear();

                //return View("Acompanhamento", new { id = model.CadastroID });
                return RedirectToAction("Acompanhamento", "Ti01", new { id = t.CadastroID });


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Precisa passar em qual tipo de ação?

Comment: @Lucas Uma ActionResult

Comment: Você quer fazer POST de uma lista de ids?

Comment: Uso esse ID para popular um registro no banco de dados

Comment: O ideal seria passar esse ID como model, mas colocando isto dentro o foreach, ele retorna nulo para o controller.

Comment: Coloque um exemplo do seu controller.

Comment: Controller adicionado.

Comment: Seu método na controller ta recebendo o objeto Ti01Model, mas aparentemente sua view esta enviando outro objeto. Quando faz o submit, você quer enviar os ids que estão nos 2 foreach?

Comment: Na view eu estou usando Radio buttons, então só tem como selecionar uma opção (1 ID)

Comment: O foreach está ali para imprimir duas listas diferentes

Comment: Entendi. Do jeito que sua controller esta, ela recebe somente um objeto, você terá que muda-la para List<Ti01Model>. Fora isso, terá que fazer modificações na view para que consiga enviar uma lista de Ti01Model em um unico post

Comment: Para este caso, acho mais simples fazer um post com alguma biblioteca javascript, pode ser o jQuery, por exemplo. Fazer com o razor, fica complexo, trabalhoso e dificil de manter.

Comment: Com razor é mais simples em casos onde voce atualiza 1 registro por requisição. Quando voce quer enviar multiplos registros em uma unica requisição, vale a pena considerar a chamada por alguma biblioteca javascript.

Comment: Como seria feito por jQuery, por exemplo?

Comment: Já existe uma solução para isso: https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/